# Why must 'require' be evaluated in a separate expression to use of the package

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have some lisp initialisation code:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (require 'asdf))

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (push #p"c\:\\lisp\\clsql-4.0.4\\" asdf:*central-registry*))
```

Why does that version compile, while this version:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (require 'asdf)
  (push #p"c\:\\lisp\\clsql-4.0.4\\" asdf:*central-registry*))
```

produces an error during compile-file in the 3rd line, with asdf an unrecognised package?

I'm using ccl, and (require 'asdf) is documented as bringing in the built-in version of ASDF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following may be inaccurate in some details, but it is approximately like this:

There are four phases that the Lisp "engine" goes through: read time, macro expansion time, compile time, and run time.

Each top-level form is first read in completely.  Reading, however, involves resolution of the respective symbols.  Since ASDF is not yet loaded during read time of your `eval-when` form, the symbol `asdf:*central-registry*` cannot be resolved yet, and this produces the mentioned read error.

Answer (score 4):

See the answer by Svante.

Sometimes you might want to work around this. Then you need to look up the symbol in the code at RUNTIME.

```
(push somepath (symbol-value (find-symbol "*CENTRAL-REGISTRY*" "ASDF")))
```

Above code can be used, because the symbol asdf:*central-registry* is not used directly but looked up at runtime using the symbol name and the package name.